# VBA loop until a row in two or more columns is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop where a today's date is entered automatically in the first column while second column is filled and to make it stop after it fills all empty cells.

The code so far:

```
Sub DateLine()
    Do
        ' Finding first empty row in column A
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ' Enter todays date in empty row in Column A
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Loop Until Range("A1").End(xlDown) = Range("B1").End(xlDown)
    End
End Sub
```

Currently it's filling the row as intended, but does not stop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauge your selection on column B. Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) to quickly locate all of the blank cells in the corresponding rows.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~surely you know which worksheet you are on
    with .range(.cells(1, 2), .cells(rows.count, 2).end(xlup))
        with .offset(0, -1)
            on error resume next
            .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).formula = "=today()"
            'alternate permanent date
            '.specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) = date
            on error goto 0
        end with
    end with
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this would work out for you:

```
Sub DateLine()
    Do

    ' Finding first empty row in column A
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ' Enter todays date in empty row in Column A
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Loop Until Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    End

End Sub
```